# How to avoid NSMutable array add object values changes before adding object to NSMutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I am new to Objective C. I had used following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ValueisFound count]; i++)
{
    NSString* ObjectName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
    ObjectName = [[NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithUTF8String:samType]) alloc]init];

    NSMutableDictionary* jsonDictionary=[TemplateClass SeparateArray:jsonValue_1 key:[arrayofKeys objectAtIndex:j] index:i];

    ObjectName = [TemplateClass JsonPharser:str1 jsonObject:jsonDictionary];

    NSMutableArray *samArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[TemplateClass JsonPharser:str1 jsonObject:jsonDictionary], nil];

    [manoj_Array addObject:samArray];

    [samArray release];
    [ObjectName release];
}
```

While executing for loop:

- at i=0, `Object` has value(number=10), now `manoj_Array` also has (number=10).
- at i=1, `Object` has value(number=12), now `manoj_Array` has (number=12,number=12).

But i want the result as `manoj_Array` has (number=10,number=12). I don't know how that array values are changing to last value.

Comment: First of all, I don't really get what you're trying to do with ObjectName. A syntax you can also try is [manoj_Array addObject:@{[TemplateClass JsonPharser:str1 jsonObject:jsonDictionary]}];. Something you can do is to log the address in memory of samArray and each object of manoj_Array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If i try " [manoj_Array addObject:@{[TemplateClass JsonPharser:str1 jsonObject:jsonDictionary]}]; " showing warning as "Expected :" What to do?

Answer (score 0):

My mind

samArray and manoj_Array is shared the memory Reference Thats why last value is insert to the manoj_Array

i = 0 value is Store by the address of 1000

i = 1 value is Store by the address of 1002

but manoj_Array share the memory so change the Last value is Added to manoj_Array

Comment: Yes sir. But how to avoid it?

Comment: Try to Release and retain the variable memory

Answer (score 0):

You can implement KVO in order to know when a value has changed and handle its behaviour.